Micro_ros_agent build getting stuck at 9 %
i'm trying to build the micro_ros_agent on my raspberry pi 3 but it keeps getting stuck at 9%, how can i fix this ?
i've tried rebuilding on a new workspace multiple times and still the same problem.
i don't get any output since it just gets stuck in the processing phase

Is your screen freezing or something else happening?
